# Lightweight cipher type for CipherInputStream and CipherOutputStream

Tags: android, security, encryption

I am using a 128-bit AES cipher algorithm. But the program takes a long time, since the files to encrypt are big.

I was wondering if there is a more light cipher algorithm to use in Android. I can't find a list of supported ciphers in Android.

Comment: DES is slower than AES and less secure.  With a large file, then it is likely that I/O takes a long time.  Try timing just reading and writing the file with a null cypher.  That will give you the minimum time, before any cryptographic processing.  Then you can decide if it is worth playing with the crypto or looking at speeding up the I/O.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use shorter keys with AES instead? You can try OpenSSL build as native code, but I guess dalvik already uses optimized libraries, I don't think it will help. There are good reasons AES takes some time, by choosing something faster, you will have to lower real security.

I suggest you should not encrypt whole file if you need speed. Instead, encrypt only header or parts of file, without which rest of file is not useful. However it depends on what data you are encrypting and will not work for generic data files.

Comment: I am mainly working with ZIP, PNG and JSON files.However the files causing problems are the ZIP files since they are big. To read them I am using ZipFile.
I encrypt the file as I am downloading it. And to unzip it, I decrypt the whole ZIP file into the private space, and extract all the files